# How to return points on a square as an array?

Tags: python, geometry

I am currently trying to figure out how to return the perimeter of a square that can then be used as an input to calculate a charge density. Specifically, the charge is uniform around the perimeter of the square and is then used to calculate the potential and charge density.

This is the code that I have for a point charge.

```
def Q(i,j,x_max,y_max,delta):
     x_dist=math.exp(-(i*delta-x_max/2.0)*(i*delta-x_max/2.0)/(1.0*delta*delta))
     y_dist=math.exp(-(j*delta-y_max/2.0)*(j*delta-y_max/2.0)/(1.0*delta*delta))
     return x_dist*y_dist
```

I've found this very intriguing website that hints that I can accomplish this by using the equation x^(a very large number) + y^(a very large number) = 1 to approximate a square. This intrigued me, so I was trying to create the points on a square to use as the source of the charge.

http://polymathprogrammer.com/2010/03/01/answered-can-you-describe-a-square-with-1-equation/

I've tried the below, but that, of course, only returns one point.

```
return math.pow(x_dist,1000000)-1
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Are you wanting to measure flux? Density of charge through an area...

Comment: Why can't you trace out the perimeter directly, i.e. by using two nested loops. Why do you need an approximate analytical formula?

Comment: You are not returning a point, you are returning a single value. math.pow does not return a list, so you will get a single number, then subtract 1 from it.

You need to make a list, lets call it points,

points = []

append your points to it and return that.

Comment: @NPE Interesting suggestion. Some friends of mine have approached this solution, but I have been unsuccessful in getting it to work. Something like this you mean? if i*delta == (9.0*x_max)/20.0 or i*delta == (11.0*x_max)/20.0:
 #       if j*delta == (9.0*y_max)/20.0 or j*delta == (11.0*y_max)/20.0:
  #          return 1/delta
   # else:
    #    return 0.0

Comment: No, I mean using two nested loops (or linspace as @a_guest has done below).

Comment: Hmm. I see. the code makes sense to me, but I do not have numpy installed, and I am having significant trouble with it. I've looked at several solutions online, but they are not that helpful.

Comment: @NPE I've also found several solutions for using a nested loop, but all of them include a phrase end=" ", which does not seem to be recognized by my program.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function

Comment: @brinraeven I updated my answer with a snippet that doesn't use numpy. The idea is the same, compute the points on the four edges, then concatenate.

Answer (score 3):

You can compute the points on the perimeter directly using [`np.linspace`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html). Counting `x` from left to right and `y` from bottom to top, you can use the following:

```
import numpy as np


def square(top_left, l, n):
    top = np.stack(
        [np.linspace(top_left[0], top_left[0] + l, n//4 + 1),
         np.full(n//4 + 1, top_left[1])],
         axis=1
    )[:-1]
    left = np.stack(
        [np.full(n//4 + 1, top_left[0]),
         np.linspace(top_left[1], top_left[1] - l, n//4 + 1)],
         axis=1
    )[:-1]
    right = left.copy()
    right[:, 0] += l
    bottom = top.copy()
    bottom[:, 1] -= l
    return np.concatenate([top, right, bottom, left])
```

Which gives for example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

s = square((0, 0), 2, 400)
plt.plot(s[:, 0], s[:, 1], 'o')
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

[image: Square]

---

If you cannot use numpy for whatever reasons, it's not too much trouble to (re-)create the functionality to the required degree (see for example the source code of [`np.linspace`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/d1e0a43ff910e15034997b9b646b38014382fe6e/numpy/core/function_base.py#L28) as an orientation):

```
def linspace(a, b, n):
    return [a + (b - a) / (n - 1) * i for i in range(n)]


def full(n, x):
    return n * [x]


def square(top_left, l, n):
    top = list(zip(
        linspace(top_left[0], top_left[0] + l, n//4 + 1),
        full(n//4 + 1, top_left[1])
    ))
    left = list(zip(
        full(n//4 + 1, top_left[0]),
        linspace(top_left[1], top_left[1] - l, n//4 + 1)
    ))
    right = [(x + l, y) for x, y in left]
    bottom = [(x, y - l) for x, y in top]
    return top + right + bottom + left
```

Comment: Thanks @a_guest. This looks like it would work very well. Honestly, though, I'm just not far enough along in understanding coding or python to be able to implement this. This question has been thrown at me without the knowledge or tools to understand what's being asked. I appreciate your help. I just don't think I'm going to be able to complete this.

Answer (score 0):

rectangles and squares can be readily made using numpy.  The pattern can be used as a seed and repeated if you need a grid of rectangles.
For example, produce a 5 unit square

```
import numpy as np
dx = 5
dy = 5
X = [0.0, 0.0, dx, dx, 0.0]       # X, Y values for a unit square
Y = [0.0, dy, dy, 0.0, 0.0]
a = np.array(list(zip(X, Y)))
```

A bit of overkill for small polygons, but einsum can readily be brought into play for calculating perimeters of geometries or hundreds or thousands of coordinate pairs.

```
a = np.reshape(a, (1,) + a.shape)
diff = a[:, 0:-1] - a[:, 1:]
d_leng = np.sqrt(np.einsum('ijk,ijk->ij', diff, diff)).squeeze()
length = np.sum(d_leng.flatten())
```

so for the simple polygon (first and last point are duplicates to ensure closure), the coordinates and side and total lengths are as follows

```
d_leng
array([5., 5., 5., 5.])

length
20.0

a
array([[[0., 0.],
        [0., 5.],
        [5., 5.],
        [5., 0.],
        [0., 0.]]])
```

If you need a different origin point prior to beginning, that can be accomplished simply...

```
a + [10, 10]
array([[[10., 10.],
        [10., 15.],
        [15., 15.],
        [15., 10.],
        [10., 10.]]])
```